# How to map a rotated square onto another array and edit the values in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, diagonal

I have a 15000x7500 numpy array which is representing the surface of a planet and then the 4 corners of a field of view of a satellite projected onto the surface. I have these 4 corners as the indexes of the corners of the square I want to edit.

This field of view can be at any angle and I want to be able to change all the values of the array within this square from 0 to 1 to see what part of the surface it sees.

I know how to do it with indexes if it is in the same orientation as the columns and rows, just not if it is off-axis.

I've added some pictures from Excel to try to demonstrate what I mean:

[image: Example]

I know there is a numpy function to find diagonals however this works by taking the main diagonal, with an offset which isn't what I'm looking for. Is there a different numpy or other command I can use to do this?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: It is not very clear to me what you tried to achieve but It looks like a rotation (+ a view) can to the job. Note that for pictures, OpenCV can provide more useful features than Numpy.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I have fixed the problem by using the scikit-image package and the command skimage.draw.polygon 

This command allows me to map the corners of the polygon then edit the array values that fall inside the region, even if they are across diagonals.

Thanks for your help though and I apologise for not explaining very well!